# psychopy website does not give a fix for output file doubeling data

Tags: file-io, psychopy

Here is some of the code...
Whenever I get an output file I get a doubling of data.

```py
       #For each record in keypress, a line is created in the file
        keyPress = []
        keyPress.append(event.waitKeys(keyList=['s','d'],timeStamped=clock))
        for key in keyPress:
            for l, t in key:
                f.write(str(images[index]) + "\t iteration \t" + str(k + 1) + "\t" + l + "\t" + str(t)+"\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You got a few downvotes since the code is not reproducible since it assumes that several variables are defined, e.g. ``clock`` and ``f``. Also, it is not entirely clear what you mean by "doubling of data". In each row, as several rows or what? Add the contents of the save-file to make it clear what it looks like and show what you would like it yo look like. Would you do the effort to update your question with these things so this is a nice reference for future users in the same position as you? Then you may just turn those downvotes into upvotes :-)

Comment: Also, the title should describe the problem. Is your problem that the code doesn't do what you want it to do or that psychopy.org doesn't contain a solution for your particular problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that are unclear here and I haven't managed to reproduce it. But I will give my shot at an answer anyway. First, `event.waitKeys` returns just one response, so it is really not necessary to loop over them. So I'd just do

```py
l, t = event.waitKeys(keyList=['s','d'],timeStamped=clock)[0]
```

... which is much nicer. So a full reproducible solution would be this:

```py
# Set things up
from psychopy import visual, event, core
win = visual.Window()
clock = core.Clock()
f = open('log.tsv', 'a')

# Record responses for a few trials and save
for trial in range(5):
    l, t = event.waitKeys(keyList=['s','d'], timeStamped=clock)[0]  # [0] extracts the first (and only) element, i.e. the (key, rt) tuple which is then unpacked into l and t.
    f.write('trial' + trial + '\tkey' + l + "\tRT" + str(t) + "\n")
f.close()
```

Instead of creating your log files manually like this, consider using the `csv` module or psychopy's own `data.TrialHandler`. Usually it's nice to represent trials using a `dict` and save responses together with the properties of each trial. the `csv` module has a `DictWriter` method.